# The mapreduce program is not giving me any output.Could somebody have a look into it?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am not getting output in this program.When I am runnning this mapreduce program , I am not getting any result.

Inputfile: dict1.txt

```
apple,seo
apple,sev
dog,kukura
dog,kutta
cat,bilei
cat,billi
```

Output I want :

```
apple seo|sev
dog kukura|kutta
cat bilei|billi
```

Mapper class code :

```
package com.accure.Dict;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;


public class DictMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

      private Text word = new Text();
public void map(Text key,Text value,OutputCollector<Text,Text> output,Reporter reporter) throws IOException{

    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
          while (itr.hasMoreTokens())
                {

              System.out.println(key);
                    word.set(itr.nextToken());
                    output.collect(key, word);
            }
}



}
```

Reducer code :

```
package com.accure.Dict;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;


import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class DictReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

                private Text result = new Text();

                public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output,Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                    String translations = "";

                while(values.hasNext()){
                        translations += "|" + values.next().toString();
                    }

                    result.set(translations);
                    output.collect(key,result);
            }



                }
```

Driver code :

```
package com.accure.driver;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

import com.accure.Dict.DictMapper;
import com.accure.Dict.DictReducer;
public class DictDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        JobConf conf=new JobConf();
        conf.setJobName("wordcount_pradosh");
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME","accure");

        conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://host2.hadoop.career.com:54310/");
        conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi","accuregrp");
        conf.set("mapred.job.tracker","host2.hadoop.career.com:54311");

        /*mapper and reduce class */
        conf.setMapperClass(DictMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(DictReducer.class);

        /*This particular jar file has your classes*/
        conf.setJarByClass(DictMapper.class);

        Path inputPath= new Path("/myCareer/pradosh/input");
        Path outputPath=new Path("/myCareer/pradosh/output"+System.currentTimeMillis());


        /*input and output directory path */
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,inputPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,outputPath);

        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        /*output key and value class*/
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        /*input and output format */

        conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class); /*Here the file is a text file*/
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        JobClient.runJob(conf);


    }

}
```

output log :

```
14/04/02 08:33:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201404010637_0011
14/04/02 08:33:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/04/02 08:33:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/04/02 08:33:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/04/02 08:34:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 16%
14/04/02 08:34:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201404010637_0011
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 29
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=33692
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=2
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=25327
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=92
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=6
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=336
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=169311
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=12
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=6
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=12
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=246685696
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=2650
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=61
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=244
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=392347648
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2173820928
14/04/02 08:34:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading input you are setting input format as : KeyValueTextInputFormat

This expects the Byte separator b/w key and value. In you input you key and value are separated by "," hence the whole text goes as key and value would be empty.

This is why it is not going into the below loop of your mapper:

```
while (itr.hasMoreTokens())
            {

          System.out.println(key);
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                output.collect(key, word);
        }
```

You should tokenize your key and take the first split and key and second split as value.

This is evidenced in the logs : map Input Records : 6 but Map output records=0

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But what do you mean when you say say " This expects the Byte separator b/w key and value " ?    Could you please elaborate how does the KeyValueTextInputFormat takes key and value?

Comment: Refer the documentation : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/KeyValueTextInputFormat.html . Else you could use TextInputFormat which would give the key as byte offset and value as the whole line of data.

Comment: Thanks. I read that. it's written there "Each line is divided into key and value parts by a separator byte" . What does it mean by separator byte?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Venkat . You are bang on. It resolved the issue. I got the desired result. Just one request ,  if you could put a bit of light on different type of input class and how the keys and values are read differently?

Comment: InoutFormat you use determines your key and value. You have various options for InputFormat: For text input data you have KeyValueTextInputFormat & TextInputFormat . Otherwise if the data is being processed though an earlier Map Reduce program you can use Serialized files. These are basically extension of Writable formats.  Here the input file itself is in key value format. You also have Formats for HBase files. If you data is multi line e..g. XML/JSON you use streaming input formats defined in Hadoop Streaming package. Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: Ok . Between I want to process a xml file. But over internet I am finding many sites , they are hard to understand.Could you please provide an apt link which have nice explanation ?

Comment: Here you go : http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks.Let me go through it.